# Need Clarifiaction to create a web app consuming a Workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

The application is like a document approval system. Came across these methods and not sure how to make use of the method 1. But familiar with method 2.

**Method 1**

- WCF Workflow Service Application (.NET 4.5) option provided in visual
  studio. [Look here](http://postimg.org/image/8g1lsw8bl/)

**Method 2**

- Like here
  [WCF+WF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/400714/Best-Practice-Architecture-with-Workflow-Foundatio).
  Using WCF layer to create an instance of WF library.

---

Are these just different ways to achieve the same objective to host WF as a web service ?

If so how an ASP.NET application can consume service application created from first method ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are indeed different approachs to achieve the same think.

**Method 1** is using what is called a [Workflow Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456788.aspx). With this your WCF service is, effectively, a workflow where the endpoints are ReceiveAndSendReply activities.

When you want to change service logic you alter your workflow and deploy it to IIS. Its a very simple process and there're a variety of tools to help you with it, where [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx) is a standard. You can see which workflows are running, idle/persisted or suspended, etc.

**Method 2** is adding a layer of complexity because, basically, it uses a *normal* WCF service to call a workflow. You don't have the flexibility of Workflow Services and the deploy process is unnecessarily more complex.

---

Go for Method 1 and don't look back. It's the standard way of doing it and perfect, for example, for [long running workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432975.aspx).